# Primary Id in two table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with various fields and primary auto_increment integral ids. I want to combine both of them by ids. How can i be sure that the id which was assigned to a a particular row of fields in one table will be the same as that of another row from the other table? As while issuing an id, we don't know what is actually assigned so the ids of two table may not match at all. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I just voted to close your question because I really cannot tell what you are looking for.  It is helpful to include examples of data and results with a question, specifying the database engine you are using, and any attempts you have tried.

Comment: The one who understood has already answered, and i got the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is typically handled using `FOREIGN KEY` relationships. I also assume when you mean *combine* you want to `JOIN` the result set. With a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, if an `id` changes in the parent table, it will cascade to the child table.

[Here's a tutorial from SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/)